get all gdal Config Options
For debugging purposes it would be great to being able to access all gdal ConfigOptions at once.
I want to compare 2 different environments (one locally, one in a docker build)
I found this list : https://gdal.org/en/latest/user/configoptions.html
and while I am able to access all of these options individually like
gdal.GetConfigOption('GDAL_HTTP_SSLKEY')
and write them to a log-file
this is super cumbersome with more then 400 options in total.
Is there a way to access all options at the same time?
I would assume something like gdal.AllConfigOptions()

Not that I am aware of. This GDAL issue might be a good place to look how to get such a list: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7873#issue-1732559657
